# best robust feature detectors for detecting similarities among archeological signs

Tags: computer-vision, edge-detection, local-features

I would like to implement edge detectors for creating a feature vector for archeological signs.
Which are best features, algorithms to retrieve? That could be loaded in a Support vector machine for classification.

If there are in the image only signs with a uniform background it's better converting an image in a binary image and calculate convexHull, solidity, eccentricity, elongation of the archeological signs. 
Then, what i do? I insert these data in a vector and put every vector of every image in a Support Vector Machine for training?

How can i measure "distance", similarities among images?

Comment: What do you mean archaeological signs?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between *edge detection* and *feature detection*, which is usually a *corner detection* (e.g. Harris corner detector), *blob detection* or even *region detection* (e.g. MSER).

Once the features are detected in your image, they are described in some way. For point features (corners), there are many different descriptors.

I think the simplest yet powerful one is simply taking a patch around the detected feature location. The patch can be quite large and should be rotated in the direction of dominant orientation (for rotational invariance).

The feature vector can consist of just horizontal and vertical image gradients. For a 64 by 64 pixel patch, this would lead to 4096 dimensional vector. This is quite large, but can be effectively reduced by PCA (Principal Component Analysis). This is quite slow but provides good quality and robustness of the descriptor comparable to SIFT or SURF descriptors.

The SURF descriptor is based on Haar wavelet and is also quite easy to implement - it can produce smaller descriptor and hence PCA is not necessary.

You can take a look on [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/projects/trade-off/papers/mikolajczykpami05.pdf) comparing various feature descriptors.

Comment: ok ,thank you, in meanwhile i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056646/python-opencv-find-black-areas-in-a-binary-image, they talk about, convexHull, solidity, eccentricity..., i can use also these kind of features to create my feature vector or i'm wrong?

Comment: @postgres: Convex hull, eccentricity (...) are usually used for binary images, (typically for connected components). If you can find a way to binarize the signs you want to detect in a repeatable way and if the binarization doesn't remove too much information (hard to tell without any sample images), then features like these are often very robust and very simple to calculate.

Comment: like this: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#7qwbdxtqjqity4d

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#tsm6bwn39n5rhst http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#fh6nhvhe2pl1vpj

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#evbav4nda3d9emy                  http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#6dxeabtd0lnhoex

Comment: Can you use a different image host? None of the links worked for me.

Comment: try these: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?7qwbdxtqjqity4d http://www.mediafire.com/view/?tsm6bwn39n5rhst   http://www.mediafire.com/view/?6dxeabtd0lnhoex http://www.mediafire.com/view/?19t38v6q0zndk3f http://www.mediafire.com/view/?evbav4nda3d9emy

Comment: You can add images in your question - this will make it more probable of being understood and answered well.

Comment: yes but i can't because i'm new in this site. Now in the last comment images are visible!

Comment: it's possible with my images?

Comment: Do I insert these data in a vector and put every vector of every image in a Support Vector Machine for training? How can i measure "distance", similarities among images?